# define array of class object at time of declaration with val.Class with array in constructor initializer list & ptr members assigned with member array

Tags: c++, gnu

This is my class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
class abc{
private:
    //int *px=x;
    //int *py=y;
    //int *pz=z;
public:
    int x[10];
    int y[10];
    int z[10];
    int *px=x;
    int *py=y;
    int *pz=z;
    abc(const int _px[],int _py[],int _pz[]):x{{10}},y{{10}},z{{10}}
    {

    }

};
```

I want to keep x,y,z private,

What I like to do is in main I want to declare and define array of `abc` and assigned the array elements so define it in the start. I tried something like this

```
 abc obj[5]={{{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}},{{...},...},.....}
```

so `obj[0]->x[]={1,1,1}, obj[0]->y={2,2,2} obj[0]->z={3,3,3}` for `abc obj[0]` but its not compiling. Its only allowing `abc obj[5]={/*not inner curly brackets values*/}`

so question is how to assign values to obj at declaration (also defining it)
if above not possible then  how to assign to x, y, z through px,py,pz pointers (do I need memcpy for this? but don't know how to do it)

I can also keep the x,y,z public

Comment: Can u answer my question please

Comment: What's the purpose of `:x{{10}},y{{10}},z{{10}}`?

Comment: Using `std::vector` (or `std::array`) would allow to take initializer_list.

Comment: @Jarod42 for accessing elements or defining vector how will I do? Can u give me code example for that. Thanks for ur comment if vector is normally used then can u please show example to creating vector and defining it

Comment: @Jarod42 how to create vector for my class object which is vector and define it at declaration

Comment: You specifically ask about private x,y,z. Please show a [mre] of how you do it for public, x,y,z, in order to focus your question on what has you stuck and avoid any hickup with side issues you missed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `std::array`, you might do

```
class abc{
public:
    std::array<int, 10> x;
    std::array<int, 10> y;
    std::array<int, 10> z;

    abc(const std::array<int, 10>& x,
        const std::array<int, 10>& y,
        const std::array<int, 10>& z) : x{x},y{y},z{z}
    {}

private: // Not sure why you want those members :-/ Care with copy-constructor
    int* px = x.data();
    int* py = y.data();
    int* pz = z.data();
};
```

With usage similar to

```
abc obj[2] = {
    {{1,1,1},{2,2,2},{3,3,3}},
    {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
     {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
     {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
    }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5d70a2e0c5fa0a1)

Comment: So by looking at this example of yours I am think this way I can do c-like tricks in member functions of `class abc` that I will implement like memcpy and linux system programming work. Is this thinking of mine is correct I mean the way I tried to relate things. Is it possible?

Comment: Can I use linux mmap and sockets api etc. In member c++ class functions?

Comment: Not sure to understand completely yours questions, but you can call function to initialize members, or in constructor/destructor body.

Comment: Was just making sure built in c function can I use in c++ class members did not get the answer. Only thing hindering me to explore c++

Comment: Linux socket() mmap etc.

Comment: I really like this solution u offered

Comment: But really dont know yet after looking at ur code how to create vector object and define or populate it. Can u please add that. Or need another question. Thanks

Comment: Added possible usage and demo.